# Redirect to a page when user click on leave this page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement when a user closes its browser, a pop apppear, when user click on leave this page then it will redirect to another page.

For this I have tried

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return 'Are you sure?';
}
    </script>
```

POP up window is appearing. But I don't know how redirect to a page when user click on leave this page.
Plz provide me solutions

Comment: you use confirm box in javascript

Comment: Take a look here:[Javascript, Can I “redirect” user in onbeforeunload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408922/javascript-can-i-redirect-user-in-onbeforeunload-if-cant-how-to)

Comment: using javascript use window.location.href='@Url.Action("action","controllername")'

Comment: window.location.href=window.location.href

Answer (score -1):

By using your code

> ```
> <script language="JavaScript">
>   window.onbeforeunload = function() {   return 'Are you sure?'; }
> </script>
> ```

In your html, add redirect `<a>`

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_self"> Change url </a>
```

After click `<a>`, the confirm message will popup

==============Edit

When clicking `<a>`, `window.onbeforeunload` will trigger, 
that's mean confirm message popup.

Comment: this is not an answer to the OP's question. he wants to triggere redirect. not (like you suggest) click to navigate

Comment: @RoyiNamir, by clicking close in browser, the browser will close the browser, not by the native javascript. That's why I suggest him others.

Comment: suggest him others != what the op wants. I'll emphasize : **Redirect to a page when user click on leave this page**

Comment: Huei Tan i Just want when a user click on the leave this page, it will redirect to another page only..

Comment: @Omega Do you need a confirm popup message ?