# How to navigate user to specific page using window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to navigate user to particular page using onbeforeunload. Is there a way to implement it?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          //return 'The changes you made will be lost if you navigate away from this page.';
          if (flag) {
              navigateTo('index');
              else {
                  navigateTo('list');
              }
          }
          return 'The changes you made will be lost if you navigate away from this page.';
      };
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408922/javascript-can-i-redirect-user-in-onbeforeunload-if-cant-how-to

Comment: Can someone answer this question? I already saw that link. On Stack somebody cares to read about requirements or everybody is just behind badges?