# How to redirect page when javascript return is true?

Tags: javascript

**NOTICE:** Not duplicate. The answer given there doesn't work.
I want to warn a user on page reload after filling a form data with a message and then redirect them to the main page. To do so, I am using `window.onbeforeunload` function. I want to know what if I want to redirect the user after return is true. I know after `return` any method is unreachable. But, I want an option.
Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return true;

}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. Do you have any more code?

Comment: I have a form above this, and I want to warn a user when he tries to reload the page and then redirect him if he chooses to reload.

Comment: Not sure if the browsers allow redirects in this function, but just use `window.location.href = 'url';` to redirect.

Comment: already tried, doesn't work.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 All i want is to redirect a user when he tries to reload the page with an alert message.

Comment: Just looked it up, the browsers disallow redirects in this context. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408922/javascript-can-i-redirect-user-in-onbeforeunload-if-cant-how-to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, Can I "redirect" user in onbeforeunload? If cant, how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408922/javascript-can-i-redirect-user-in-onbeforeunload-if-cant-how-to)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 great research on my question.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible because this would be a pretty big security issue if you could guess or intercept the URL the user is going to (phishing hole) or a UX problem.

You type in a URL, hit enter, get a warning about leaving the page, and all over a sudden you're on some random website or you can't leave, it just keeps bringing you back.

You can try simply this to see it doesn't work even if its the only thing it tries to do.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.location = 'https://google.com'
}
```